# Passing list of strings to another activity and show them! Android

Tags: android, arrays, string, listview

I don't have a clue how to do it. I have tried with arrays but couldn't managed to get it to work. Even tried to get IDs from database and then pass it to next activity and then call it from database to get the text, but again couldn't managed to get it to work. I guesse arrays are my weak spot. Can somebody help me?

In the main activity there are numerous word that are taken from database, I would need to show them in the second activity. How do you do that?

Here is code from 1. activity:

```
public class Game extends Activity implements SensorEventListener  {
    int busy = 0;
    int nagni = 0;
    static TextView word;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private boolean timerHasStarted = false;
    public TextView text;
    private final long startTime = 60 * 1000;
    private final long interval = 1 * 1000;
    int cat4;
    private SensorManager sManager;
    Sensor accelerometer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        //senzor gibanja
        sManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer=sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timer2);
        countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
        text.setText(text.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime / 1000));
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        cat4 = intent.getIntExtra("cat3", 0);

        // Font path
        String fontPath = "AdventureRR.otf";

        // text view label
        TextView ourText3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        // Loading Font Face
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);

        // Applying font

        ourText3.setTypeface(tf);


        set();

        countDownTimer.start();
        timerHasStarted = true;

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_game, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void set(){
        SQLiteDatabase db;


        String que = "";
        db=openOrCreateDatabase("baza.db",MODE_PRIVATE, null);


        Cursor cd=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM question WHERE cat=" + cat4 + " AND used = 1", null);
        cd.moveToFirst();

        que=cd.getString(cd.getColumnIndex("text"));

        //patch
        String id2=(cd.getString(cd.getColumnIndex("id")));
        int idd2=Integer.parseInt(id2);
        db.execSQL("UPDATE question SET used=0 WHERE id ="+idd2+";");


        word = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        word.setText("");
        word.setText(que);


        db.close();
        busy = 0;
    }




    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {


        //else it will output the Roll, Pitch and Yawn values
        if (event.values[2]>8){
            if (busy == 0){

                if (nagni == 0){

                Intent i = new Intent(this,Pass.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);

                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                    public void run() {
                         //Do something after 1000ms
                         set();
                    }
                }, 1000);
                }
            }

            busy = 1;

        }
        else if(event.values[2]<-8){

            if (busy == 0){

                if (nagni == 0){


                Intent i = new Intent(this,Correct.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);

                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Do something after 1000ms
                        set();
                    }
                }, 1000);
                }
            }
            busy = 1;

        }

        else{
            busy = 0;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
        public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            text.setText("END!");

            nagni=1;

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Intent i = new Intent(Game.this, Results.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            }, 1500);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if (millisUntilFinished>10000){
            text.setText("0:" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }
            else if (millisUntilFinished<10000){
            text.setText("0:0" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // do nothing.
    }



}
```

Here is my 2. activity:

```
public class Results extends Activity  {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);

        final ImageButton one = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        final ImageButton two = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);


        one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(Results.this, Main.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent= new Intent(Results.this, Instructions.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        // Font path
        String fontPath = "AdventureRR.otf";

        // text view label
        TextView ourText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        // Loading Font Face
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);

        // Applying font

        ourText.setTypeface(tf);





    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_results, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // do nothing.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

While starting next activity for intent add list as follows

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("data", list);
```

and use it in next activity as follows

```
getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("data");
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `intent.putExtra` in your first activity and `intent.getExtra()` in the second activity

Here is an example:

**Activity1**

```
intent.putExtra(tag, stringArray);
```

**Activity2**

```
getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray(key);
```